# How to include hash fragment in redirect uri for authentication provider

Tags: url, asp.net-core, openid-connect

I have asp.net core 2.1 app with open id connect authentication:

```
services.AddAuthentication(...)
    .AddCookie(...)
    .AddOpenIdConnect(...);
```

When unauthenticated user visits url: **`/path?somequery#somehashfragment`**, it is redirected to authentication providers's login page and than back to **`/path?somequery`**, but the hash fragment is stripped out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

URL hash fragments do not go out of the browser. That mean if you put a hash fragment to a URL in your browser and visit it, fragment won't reach the server end. Solution would be to make this parameter a query parameter.

From OIDC perspective this is used for implicit flow to prevent token stealing. This is highlighted in specification's [Implicit Flow Threats section](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#ImplicitFlowThreats).

Answer (score 1):

Ran into this issue using Aurelia as the front end framework. This essentially broke the redirect url functionality for the application because Aurelia uses the # to determine its internal routing.

After much trial and error, I found if the hash is url encoded then it will pass properly to the server. Attaching this little bit of javascript onto the login.cshtml file solved this issue.

```
<script>
    if (window.location.hash && window.location.hash != '') {
        window.location.href = window.location.origin +
            window.location.pathname +
            window.location.search +
            encodeURIComponent(window.location.hash);
    }
</script>
```

Hopefully this helps!